# When $0$ is mentioned at anytime when talking about Fields, does this mean we are talking about the number $0$, or is it the additive identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

When talking about fields, such as the field axioms and the theorems that follow, when $0$ is mentioned at anytime, does this mean we are talking about the number $0$, or is it the additive identity?

Comment: I believe the case is the latter part of your question.

Comment: I concur with graydad.

Comment: It's the additive identity; whether it's "the number" $0$ depends on your definition of that phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that by **the** number zero you are referring to $0$
as an element of $\mathbb{N}$.

Say we have a field $\mathbb{F}$ and denote the zero element of $\mathbb{F}$
by $0_{\mathbb{F}}$, then statements like 
$$
\alpha=0,\alpha\cdot0,\alpha+0
$$

are referring to $0_{\mathbb{F}}$. However statements like 
$$
|\{a\in\mathbb{F}\mid\text{a satisfies...}\}|=0
$$

are referring to the number zero, that is, as a counting number.

I hope that the difference is clear from the examples.